# Replace class of child div that contains a certain word in the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace the class of a child div that contains a certain word in its class.

**how it looks like**

```
<div class="iti__selected-flag">
<div class="iti__flag iti__us"></div>
<div class="iti__row"></div>
</div>
```

I need to dynamically change the class `iti__us`. Thing is the country is never known in the DOM/HTML and is changed based on user input. So it could be `ca`, `uk`.. etc. It's not always the same. If I knew the class name in advance, it would be no problem to simply remove the class then add the new. How can I do this?

**My codes**

```
var countryflag = data.flag; //iti__uk
$('.iti__flag').addClass(countryflag);
```

Comment: `$('.iti__selected-flag .iti__flag').removeClass().addClass('iti__flag ' + countryflag);`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Lawrence of course! Two heads alwayas better than one lol. I give you the credits if you want them.